# Routing in reactjs application

Tags: reactjs

I have two parts in my website - a menu that has redirections on click, and a content div where I load something via ajax when I click on a link from this menu.

The menu is different when I logged in as a user, and when I logged in as an admin.

How do I structure the reactjs classes in the above situation? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I find that [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) is sufficiently flexible to suit your scenario. It's a bit tricky to find "best practices" in the react community right now and it's better to understand what you're trying to do (you have done this) and then understand the tools available: react itself, react-router, and perhaps redux and react-redux as a way to check an application state [e.g. logged in as admin] in order to decide which links to display.